# Asking a question about power steering pump

Tags: ford, power-steering, taurus

I have a 2004 Ford Taurus, one of the power steering pump hoses is not on, Can you drive it like that or not?

Comment: How did the hose come off? Seems like it would be leaking fluid badly. This might result in damage to the pump, and possibly a fire hazard depending on where the fluid is going.

Answer (score 1):

Running a power steering pump without fluid will damage the pump quickly, then eventually the power rack and pinion unit.